# Export SMS messages and save in Excel Format

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to develop a program in order to Export SMS messages from device. 
If anyone know how to achieve please give some code snippet or any Link.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: @Viruss I just wanna export the SMS..the rest I can implement...So only need a bit help in that concern.

Comment: check `rckoenes`  and Nitin answer .

Answer (score 4):

First of it is not nice to just ask for code. We are here to  help you in any way we can but most of us make a living programming, so just giving away code is not a real option.

Second, on iOS the SMS messages cannot be read by third party apps. There is no real option to achieve what you want. A simple search on Google would have told you this.

If you are planning on releasing an app for jailbroken device then it may be possible.

Comment: Hi rckoenes, I just mentioned what  have to achieve. I just wanna know only about "Export the SMS". Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This against Apple's sandbox limits. Apps only have a very limited number of resources that it may use. and you can not fetch SMS, incoming call history or many other Feature that apple not allow to use in to Your Native app.

check ones this doc [iOS programming guild](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) so Export SMS messages from device. that is not possible in iPhone device `(Non-jailbroken)` as @rckoenes said